# why is htaccess file causing too many redirects when trying to redirect to https

Tags: .htaccess, https

I am trying to update my htaccess file to redirect from http to https but I am getting too many redirects. I have never used this type of file before so not sure if doing something very obviously wrong

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://www.xxxx.org.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I get https: // www. xxxx .org.uk/ and 301 status (spaces added to stop it linking)

Comment: yes multiple 301s

Comment: I get the same issue of multiple 301s

Comment: You have some misconfiguration as it works fine on my Apache 2.4

Comment: do you know what might be causing it? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a solution which works for those that face a similar problem in the future.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```